# azure log analytics API authentication

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

Need help in authorizing/authenticating the azure log analytics API. Does client credentials supported, if yes any examples can you share

Answer (score 0):

The Log Analytics API supports Azure Active Directory authentication with three different Azure AD OAuth2 flows:

- Client credentials
- Authorization code
- Implicit

For more information, you can refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/access-api).